# Automatic Migrations seeding and AddOrUpdate not matching, always adding

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Sessions object with the following fluent API configuration

```
HasMany(s => s.Enrollments);
HasRequired(s => s.Course).WithMany(c => c.Sessions).HasForeignKey(s => s.CourseId);
HasRequired(s => s.Teacher).WithMany(t => t.Sessions).HasForeignKey(s => s.TeacherId);
HasRequired(s => s.Term).WithMany(t => t.Sessions).HasForeignKey(s => s.TermId);
```

I am attempting to seed my data with the following (I query for each of the thisCourse, currentTerm, smith objects prior to my AddOrUpdate)

```
context.Sessions.AddOrUpdate(s => new { s.CourseId, s.TermId, s.TeacherId },
  new Session { Course = thisCourse, Term = currentTerm, Teacher = smith}
);
```

This is always resulting in an Add of:

```
<new id>   1   1   1
```

I can't figure out why my matching conditions are failing, and this is not properly updating, but always adding.

Comment: Can you pls post the FluentAPI configuration for `Course`, `Teacher` also?